# EXPO-AV cache of audio files -REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching, expo, expo-av

I am using react native to develop an app. I am currently recording audio files with expo AV and then I am able to send this files to a server. I don't really want this files to occupate memory in the mobile device.

I use the URI to send the file. However, I am wondering, am I ocupating memory of my devcie every time I use this app? I think this audio files are being saved in cache.

Here's what Im doing so far:

```
import { Audio } from "expo-av";


...

recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
const uri = recording.getURI(); // use this uri to send by formData to the server
console.log("Recording stopped and stored at", uri);
...
```

My question is, is there a way to clean this cache?

Am I really ocupating memory with these files everytime I am recording with this library?

How can I proceed to avoid a bad user experience in which the user is going to have no memory without knowing exacly why? is this a big issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using expo and my solution is to delete the file you recorded.
First import file system

```
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
```

Then call after when you're done with the file.

```
await FileSystem.deleteAsync(recording.getURI());
```

I hope it helps you.